# Azure Service Bus Backup

Tags: azure, powershell, azureservicebus, azure-cli

Is there any Powershell or AZ command to take the backup of Azure Service Bus on Production or we can export the entities via commandline?

PS: Currently taking a backup from(Service bus explorer) here manually as we have a lot of topics and subscription. Anybody with access can delete the topics and subscription and to avoid this need backup.

[image]

Comment: Considering the fact that messages in a Service Bus Queue/Subscription are very transient, I am curious to know the reason for backing up. Would you mind editing your question and explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GauravMantri Edited

Answer (score 0):

You could export an [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/export-template-portal) and export all of the entities from the namespace.

Comment: Can I import the same and retrieve in case of any failure or deletion of existing running?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. The exported items are the items that were originally successfully created and do not depend on the state changes.

Comment: I mean, if someone delete or alter anything in running production, then Can I restore it to last backup which I would have taken with export ARM Template as you mentioned as my whole purpose of taking backup is this only, otherwise no use of export.

Comment: That's exactly what happens. See the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097586/azure-service-bus-backup/57101379#comment100778131_57101379) 